# avoid page load on html image button click

Tags: load

I have code on aspx page :

```
<input id="imgBtnUpdate" type="image" src="../images/update_btn.gif" value="Update" onclick="javascript:showModalPopupUpdate();"/>
```

also Script is :

```
var popUpObj11;
    function showModalPopupUpdate() {

        popUpObj11 = window.open("AddPopup.aspx?mode=Update",
        "ModalPopUp",
        "toolbar=no," +
        "scrollbars=no," +
        "location=no," +
        "statusbar=no," +
        "menubar=no," +
        "resizable=no," +
        "width=450," +
        "height=190," +
        "left = 490," +
        "top=300"
        );
        popUpObj11.focus();
    }
```

Ok? 
When i clicking the imgBtnUpdate Button. it showing me popup which is fine. but why it reloading the parent page on which the button consisting ? please guide me... tell me solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your code as follows:

```
<input id="imgBtnUpdate" type="image" src="../images/update_btn.gif" value="Update" onclick="showModalPopupUpdate();return false;"/>
```

If the onclick event returns a false value, the browser will not execute the default action.

Comment: Thank you "return false;" part helped me.

Answer (score 2):

Return false from the event to keep the button from posting the page:

```
onclick="showModalPopupUpdate();return false;"
```

Note: The `javascript:` protocol is only used when you put script in an URL. If you use it in an event it's interpreted as a label instead.

Answer (score 1):

**[INPUT type=image Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535836(VS.85).aspx)**

> Creates an image control that, when
>   clicked, causes the form to be
>   immediately submitted.

Try giving

```
return false;
```

at the end of the function.

Better use an anchor tag and embedded image for doing this instead of `<input type="image" />`